# Why is yarn throwing an error after installing babel-loader?

Tags: reactjs, create-react-app, yarnpkg, babel-loader, react-icons

After I installed the `react-icons` package, my code threw an error saying my `babel-loader` was missing, so I installed that package too.

Next thing I knew, I ran `yarn start` and this error came up:

```
Assertion failed: (napi_create_string_utf8(env, events->events[idx].path, NAPI_AUTO_LENGTH, &args[0]) == napi_ok), function fse_dispatch_event, file ../src/fsevents.c, line 147.
error Command failed with exit code 1.
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this command.
```

I tried using `npm start` and the app started just fine.

What's wrong?

Comment: can you join? I will try to help you with my knowledge https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/227868/doubts

Answer (score 1):

I believe this is caused by an upstream [issue](https://github.com/fsevents/fsevents/issues/355) with [fsevents](https://github.com/fsevents/fsevents).